# bs4 Selectors Not Taking "image:title"

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am making a website scraper to get me all of the product names on a website. I keep getting a KeyError when trying to locate the title of the product.

HTML:

```
<url>
  <loc>
    https://shop.havenshop.ca/products/cassady-sunglasses-indigo-gunmetal
  </loc>
  <lastmod>2017-10-19T08:53:44-07:00</lastmod>
  <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
  <image:image>
    <image:loc> https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0051/7042/products/Cassady_SunglassesIndigoGunmetal1.jpg?v=1436564480</image:loc>
    <image:title>"Cassady" Sunglasses Indigo / Gunmetal</image:title>
  </image:image>
</url>
```

Python Code:

```
session = requests.session()
sitemap = session.get(link)
data = sitemap.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
items = soup.find_all("url")
for i in range(len(items)):
    for item in items[i]:
        print items[i]["image:image"]["image:title"]
```

Error:

```
KeyError: 'image:title'
```

Comment: print keys in dictionary `print( items[i]["image:image"].keys() )`

Comment: Your inner for loop is `for item in items[i]:`, so why are you printing `items[i]["image:image"]["image:title"]`?  Shouldn't that be `item["image:image"]["image:title"]`?

Comment: @JohnGordon this throws "TypeError: string indices must be integers"

Answer (score 1):

That is not HTML, that is XML. You should find your namespaced elements instead of attempting to access via attribute. This will give you your value:

```
items[i].find('image.title')
```

A full example:

```
for url in soup.find_all('url'):
    if 'Cassady' in url.find('image:title').text:
        print(url.find('image:loc').text)
```

Comment: this returns a none type?

Comment: `items[0].find('image:title')` returns `<image:title>"Cassady" Sunglasses Indigo / Gunmetal</image:title>` for me. Your code has many other errors, probably one of those.

Comment: the loop i am using is going through all of the <url> tags in the xml, so i am going through until the image:title is "Cassady" Sunglasses Indigo / Gunmetal, then i want it to return the <loc> tag of the <url> tag

Comment: i removed the for item in items[i] loop and it works, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Best option is go with bs4 solution :

Just an opinion :

If you want only all products name then You can also use regular expression if you want :

```
import re
pattern=r'<image:title>"(\w.+?)<\/image:title>'
with open('file.txt','r') as f:  #instead of file you can directly pass the url content via bs4 parser
    match=re.finditer(pattern,f.read())
    for i in match:
        print(i.group(1))
```

output:

```
Cassady" Sunglasses Indigo / Gunmetal
```